# Attach xaml style to element without explicitly stating it

Tags: silverlight

I have a problem styling/templating an **AccordionItem** in the accordion control from the [silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). For some reason, the child controls are Horizontally Aligned Left. The only way I can get to fix this is to edit the **ExpandableContentControlStyle** on the **AccordionItem**.

The style is located below:

```
<Style x:Key="ExpandableContentControlStyle1" TargetType="layoutPrimitivesToolkit:ExpandableContentControl">
  <Setter.Value>
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="layoutPrimitivesToolkit:ExpandableContentControl">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
     </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now my problem is that to have this style being attached to the AccordionItem, I have to set it:

```
<layoutToolkit:Accordion HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
   <layoutToolkit:AccordionItem Header="Hello" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ExpandableContentControlStyle="{StaticResource ExpandableContentControlStyle1}"/>
   <layoutToolkit:AccordionItem Header="Haha" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
</layoutToolkit:Accordion>
```

But those **AccordionItem** will be generated from an **ItemSource**. What I'd like to do is to have that style be applied to the generated **AccordionItem** without setting it.

PS. The above problem can become obsolete if I can just find out how to edit the (**ContentPresenter** x:Name="ContentSite") from the parent **Accordion**. I cannot edit it from none of the following template properties:

1. **ContentTemplate**
2. **ItemContainerStyle**
3. **AccordionButtonStyle**
4. **ItemsPanel**
5. **ItemTemplate**

If anyone knows what is going on with that, I'd appreciate the help or you can just help with styling of multiple elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the Accordion control myself, though typically you set the ItemContainerStyle to the style you want for each item in the list.  For instance, if you wanted a specific ListBoxItem style on a ListBox, you set the ItemContainerStyle to the ListBoxItem style you want.  I glanced at the source for the Accordion and this seems to hold true for that control as well.  Try setting the ItemContainerStyle property of the Accordion to your ExpandableContentControlStyle1.

```
<layoutToolkit:Accordion
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ExpandableContentControlStyle1}">
</layoutToolkit:Accordion>
```

To set the style outside of the control itself, create a style for the Accordion.  If you're using Silverlight 4, you can use implicit styles.  Put the following style in the `<UserControl.Resources>` section of your page.

```
<Style TargetType="layoutToolkit:Accordion">
  <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ExpandableContentControlStyle1}"/>
</Style>
```

Otherwise, with Silverlight 3 you'll have to explicitly give the style a Key and explicitly set the style on the Accordion control.

```
<Style x:Key="Control_Accordion" TargetType="layoutToolkit:Accordion">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ExpandableContentControlStyle1}"/>
</Style>

<layoutToolkit:Accordion
    Style="{StaticResource Control_Accordion}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
</layoutToolkit:Accordion>
```

Comment: no, I dont want to set the style at all. I want to have the style on the page and it automatically applies to the element. like with css.